# Pseudorandom sequence whose values can be computed directly for given seed?

Tags: random-generation

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_Blum_Shub) that Blum Blum Shub is a pseudorandom generator whose ith value can be computed directly for a given seed.  Wikipedia also says that this generator is too slow to be practical for simulation applications.

Is there any standard generator with the direct computation property that is fast enough for Monte Carlo?  Is there a reason this cannot exist?

Comment: Did I understand correctly that you intend to use the pseudo- random number generator (PRNG) for generating the random needed for Monte Carlo? If yes, why do you need a **provable** *cryptographically secure* PRNG? Any *cryptographically secure* PRNG (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator)  would do the job for you, as any statistic abnormality you find would break the PRNG (giving you a nice paper at the Crypto). Probably even *cryptographically secure* is an overkill.

Comment: No, I don't need anything cryptographically secure.  I'm just looking for a good balance between speed and randomness within the direct computation constraint.

Comment: Perhaps the simple random hash given in numerical recipes (section 7.1.4) is acceptable.  Can someone summarize the downsides?

Comment: But why do you need such thing in the first place?

Comment: To be able to flexibly multithread the number generation but have the sequence match a singlethreaded version. (?)

Comment: Thus you just need a good parallel random number generator, like [SPRNG](http://sprng.cs.fsu.edu/).

Comment: I will look at this more carefully, but on first glance it doesn't seem to fit the bill.  I need to be able to say "thread 1 will get blocks A,B,C of values to operate on, thread 2 will get blocks X,Y,Z".  The blocks may be interleaved.  And I must be able to reassemble the blocks into a single sequence matching single threaded output given the same initial seed state.

Comment: Also, the generators offered in SPRNG seem limited, although they are probably adequate.  Also, I would prefer not to introduce MPI dependencies if not necessary.  Anyway, this is getting beyond the question and forum.  I just thought it was worth asking in case there is some obvious mathematical solution that could save me some futzing.

Comment: Why does the *sequence* of Monte Carlo results matter?  Each iteration is supposed to be independent of the others, implying the results should be exchangeable.

Comment: @whuber Because the calculations performed by the current system rely on results from an earlier system that used the same sequence.  Unfortunately there is no way to eliminate this coupling.

Comment: To answer my earlier question, the random hash from NR7.1.4 is probably acceptable except it has a limited cycle length, but I think that's okay.

Comment: For your goal you don't really need to make that compromise. Standard good and fast generators such as Mersenne Twister (now used e.g. in Matlab) allow for "fast" jumping over the stream without generating all intermediate values, so that you can split a large stream in more parts one for each thread. There are three methods for that, but they're all relatively involved. Some PRNG libraries are starting to implement them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this thread: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/1281/5065
it is possible to advance to the Nth seed value of a Linear Congruential Generator in O(lg N) ops.  So the LCG is close to a random access PRNG.  Unfortunately its random quality is poor, not good enough for most Monte Carlo, but it can be used for some things...

Alternatively, there seems to be a move towards using strong hash functions for parallel generation; these are inherently randomly addressable.  It's not the simplest method to meet my constraint of being able to match a sequentially generated sequence, but it's doable.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the comments, is there any reason you can't just put a semaphore around a standard PRNG plus a counter? For example:

```
  <set a semaphore>
  myPRN = some_PNRG();
  my_number = a_counter++;
  <unset the semaphore>
```

Assuming your Monte-Carlo simulations take any substantial amount of time to run, the time spent waiting on the semaphore should be relatively insignificant.

Comment: Sorry, not really following.  This is in each thread and the semaphores are synchronization, while some_PNRG is shared state?

Comment: Ah okay, and a_counter is also shared state so allows current thread to know which values it's getting.  Yes, I think this could work, especially if I fine tuned the size of the block of numbers that each thread takes before passing on the flag.  Would be nice not to have so much synchronization, although I think you're right that contention would be not too bad.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not a pseudorandom sequence but rather a low discrepancy sequence, I have been using the [Halton sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halton_sequence) for precisely the desired property, i.e. you can calculate the $n$th number in the sequence independently of any others. My motivation for this was also multi-threaded random number generation. Aside from this feature, you may also prefer quasi-Monte Carlo for its faster rate of convergence.

Another approach to consider depending upon the number of random numbers you need is unrolling whereby you pre-generate the random numbers in a large static array which is linked at compile time. Then you can easily random access the $n$th number in the sequence and performance is pretty hard to beat!